# git pull -f not overwriting local files

Tags: git

I have a weird situation where I have no uncommitted changes locally:
[image]

But when I do a git pull(With or without -f) I get message of several merge conflicts
[image]

I just want to overwrite the local stage branch(of live server) with that in remote(as the push was done by a unprofessional dev which I have overwritten succesfully but this server somehow is not able to force pull). How do I do it?

Comment: Delete the local branch and recreate it from the remote?

Comment: If the *push* was done by an unprofessional dev, don't you want to push what *you* have to overwrite the state on the remote side rather than overwrite your local state with the bogus remote state?

Comment: @j6t I have already pushed my code to the remote overwriting his changes. but the issue is happening on the server where this code is deployed. this screenshot is of the server instance.

Comment: @Schleis definitely thats an option. But I would be interested in digging this further as to why its even happening.

Comment: The fact that `.DS_Store` files are under Git control is a huge error. You need to fix your `.gitignore` (and manually remove all those files from Git control as well).

Comment: @Schleis ended up doing it your way. Deadline was hard thats why. maybe you could put that as an answer (with perhaps a few more details according to SO standards)

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to overwrite the local stage branch(of live server) with that in remote ... How do I do it?

Locally, say:

```
git fetch
git switch -C stage origin/stage
```